# how to debug a source code of an android project that is unknown to you?

Tags: android, debugging

Suppose, you were given a project source code of an Android app, a pretty BIG sized app. ( 30+ activities, each containing 2000+ lines of codes and 200+ layout XMLs, and so on ) You don't know anything about the code unless you read line by line. Now you were given a deadline to fix some bugs, but you don't know where to start or where to put breakpoints to debug. In that case, how would you do it? How would you debug the code?
Thanks

Edit: Code is not documented. Most variables are public static and called from everywhere. Its like, "Everything is connected to everything" kinda situation.

Comment: If you are fixing a bug How come you don't know where to put Breakpoint ? At least u know the class Component visible on screen . Start from there. There is no magic stick .

Comment: The problem is that, the code is super unclean. Variable names are terrible at its worst. functions are 200+ lines each, most of the time. And I could go on and on. I'm not looking for a magical solution to be honest. I'm just looking for a solution that is less time consuming

Comment: I am afraid there is no other way . This seems some messed up codebase .

Comment: Yes, a messed up codebase, and if you are assigned a messedup codebase, with a deadline to fix some bugs, what would you do? you can't just cancel the agreement because there's a penalty you have to pay. Now, what should be done? how to debug it faster?

Comment: My advice : start by a "UI bug". Select a "screen" (no matter if Activity or Fragment for now), find its layout.xml and find the related code. Try to understand and put breakpoints in common methods: onCreate(), populate(), etc.

Comment: I don't have that much time to investigate one by one screen/activity. Already mentioned, I have a deadline.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some experience in Android, you can try and run the app and investigates the bugs they are wanting to be fixed, and see what is really going on and what should be fixed. Then you can search for the layout (xml) file of that screen where the bug is and right-click it then press "Find Usages" so then you can find the activity as well. Sadly, fixing bugs in new apps is not fast, especially if the code was written fast and poor.

Comment: This way, it would take millions of years to fix the bugs and I don't have that much time. & honestly, I do have a better solution than this, but I'm looking for a better and faster solution than that.

Comment: Then go with yours. There is no easy way to fix bugs only if your code will make other bugs along the way. And also, you should not agreed with any sort of deadline before you got a look at the codebase - so you can set some realistic expectations of how much time you have.